# <p:autoComplete completeMethod> does not specify parameter in EL expression, how does it work?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el, methodexpression

In a demo I am seeing this code. In this JSF, autoCompleteView.completeQuery is called without parameter, but this method is defined with a String Parameter in the bean. Is this allowed in JSF?

```
<p:autoComplete id="queryPojo" value="#{autoCompleteView.query}"
 completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeQuery}" var="query"
 itemLabel="#{query.displayName}" itemValue="#{query}"
 converter="queryConverter" />
```

Bean

```
public List<Query> completeQuery(String query) {

        List<Query> allQueries = service.getQueries();
        List<Query> filteredQueries = new ArrayList<Query>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allQueries.size(); i++) {
            Query skin = allQueries.get(i);
            if(skin.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                filteredQueries.add(skin);
            }
        }         
        return filteredQueries;
    }
```

Edited: The search bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SearchController {

    private String word;

    // For AutoComplete suggestions
    private Query selectedQuery;

    @Inject
    private QueryService service;

    @Inject
    private Word wordObject;

    public void search() {
        if (word != null && !word.isEmpty()) {
            wordObject.searchWord(word);;
             ...
        }else {
            System.out.println("Query can't be null!");
        } 
    }

    public List<Query> completeQuery(String query) {

        List<Query> allQueries = service.getQueries();
        List<Query> filteredQueries = new ArrayList<Query>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allQueries.size(); i++) {
            Query skin = allQueries.get(i);
            if(skin.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                filteredQueries.add(skin);
            }
        }

        return filteredQueries;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

   public Query getSelectedQuery() {

        return selectedQuery;
    }

    public void setSelectedQuery(Query selectedQuery) {
        this.selectedQuery = selectedQuery;
    }
}
```

JSF view:

```
<h:form>
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

            <p:autoComplete id="wordForm" value="#{searchController.query}"
                completeMethod="#{searchController.completeQuery}" var="query"
                itemLabel="#{query.displayName}" itemValue="#{query}"
                converter="queryConverter" forceSelection="true" />

            <p:commandButton value="search" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" **action="#{searchController.search}"** />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Since I have the p:AutoComplete form, do I still need this normal inputtext form?

```
                <h:inputText id="word" "
                    value="#{searchController.word}" />
                <h:message for="word" />
                <h:commandButton id="search" value="search"
                    action="#{searchController.search}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is allowed because the "completeMethod" automatically sets the value of the "value" tag as a Parameter inside the "completeMethod". 
With this approach you also can give an own domain object inside the value and work with it inside your backing bean "completeMethod" method.

Edit:

```
<p:autoComplete id="wordForm" value="#{searchController.word}"
completeMethod="#{searchController.completeQuery}" var="query"
itemLabel="#{query.displayName}" itemValue="#{query}"
converter="queryConverter" forceSelection="true" />
```

Comment: If I have another search() method that takes the selected query after the suggesion to perform the search. How woudl I do that? How would the serach() method get the final selected query to execute the search() method?

Comment: depends on the component you use. The p:autoComplete is a special case with its automatic query setting ability. If you hava a normal input field you have different options to perform a search. You can put your search method inside a keyup event and get the searchquery in your backing bean to perform your search. Or you create a button with an action parameter

Comment: In this cases you dont have to set the search query string as an parameter because the inputfield value is already linked inside the backingbean

Comment: Please see the edited. I want to do something like that. Is that the right approach?

Comment: the right approach but you have to set the value to your word string to map the data inside. look at my edit

Comment: I am a bit confused. You edition is the same as mine. What's the best way to execute the search() method? Or the search() method should be merged with completeQuery() method?

Comment: it is not the same you have value="#{searchController.query}" and i have value="#{searchController.word}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105776/discussion-between-user697911-and-screamingtree).